# Wpf checkbox trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

Trying to bind the `click` or `checked` event on a WPF `chekbox` to a `command` in my viewmodel, but im unsure on the technique and the event names, can anyone point me in the right direction?

For now the code compiles but the the `trigger` does not call the `FooCommand`

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding PartData.ReportIncluded, Mode=TwoWay}"  
          VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the "On" prefix of your event, i.e. OnMouseLeftButtonDown or OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

Comment: Tried OnMouseLeftButton and OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and OnChecked, nothing works

Comment: Does the i:Interaction.Triggers work for evens on other controls?

Comment: Thanks for your anwswers, if found it, the trigger is in a hirearciacal datatemplate with its own datacontext, and the fooCommand is in the usercontrol datacontext, thats why it never gets called

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense.  That's happened to me before as well.  It's hard to track down without looking at the binding errors in the output window.  I really wish .NET would find a way to discover those before runtime.